# I can't make my .htaccess file to work with MAMP

Tags: php, .htaccess, mamp

this is my first question so hi
I'm having trouble trying to open a folder in the localhost, because when I try to, I keep getting the 500 Internal Server Error. I tried changing the AllowOverride to all from the httpd.conf but it doesn't work. When I delete my .htaccess I can load the page, but it doesn't have any css, so it seems I actually need that file (I'm learning, sorry)
I googled the error and all I see is "change allowoverride to all" or some stuff about the .htaccess file that I really don't understand, and I really need it to work
The apache_error log says "error: envclause should be in the form env=envar"
I could upload my .htaccess code but it's about 1200 lines (it's from html5 boilerplate)

Answer (score 0):

You should probably not try and get .htaccess to work until you figure out why the CSS doc isn't loading. Loading your page in Chrome with the inspector open and looking at the network tab (click the CSS sub-tab) will help you find out if you're even loading the external CSS file(s) at all. If you aren't, fix your links. If you are, perhaps there are problems with your css. You can run your CSS file through a validator to see if there are some broken bits:
https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/

A 1200 line .htaccess file?! That sounds extreme to me. I'd be curious why you require so many rules. Does your error log show you which line it is breaking on and if so, can you post that line here for help?

Comment: Actually the CSS part was because (I don't know why) my whole project just reseted (luckly I had a backup)
I managed to make MAMP work, but I just had to delete the .htaccess file. I don't know what it's for, but as long as I can practice php I don't really care
Is it that important? Do I need this file?

Also, I don't know why it has 1200 lines, I just downloaded it like that from html5 boilerplate, it's mostly comments tho, instructions.

Comment: You only need it for specific reasons. Not to create a simple website. I would get rid of it or leave it blank until you have a reason to use it. .htaccess is used when you want apache configuration directives but don't want to edit httpd.conf. Using .htaccess allows you to make those changes on the fly and to take immediate effect, whereas changing httpd.conf requires restarting apache.  Rewriting URLs on the fly is an example of why most people would use .htaccess.IE: user visiting website.com/my-page-name but the rewrite changes what your code sees to website.com/index.php?page=my-page-name

Comment: So, basically I should just forget about it because I'm just learning right?
I mean, this website I'm building is just practice anyway.

Comment: Yes. Ignore it :) I took a look at https://github.com/h5bp/html5-boilerplate/blob/master/dist/.htaccess?ts=2 (if that's what you're using) and while that is important info, none of it is required for you to learn web basics. Save that stuff for later down the line when you have specific needs and learn that .htaccess could help you for those.

Comment: Then I'll just ignore ir for now
Thank you ^^